# Query to fetch the username for two columns from MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mysql. Structure of tables are below.

```
USER: userid, username

Issue: id, issue_by (userid), issue_to (userid)
```

How can we fetch the username for both issue_by and issue_to for a particular Issue?

Comment: show sample data, expected result and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to user table two times (yes, that is possible) :

```
SELECT i.id, u_by.username AS userby_name, u_to.username AS userto_name
FROM Issue AS i
LEFT JOIN `USER` AS u_by ON u_by.userid = i.issue_by
LEFT JOIN `USER` AS u_to ON u_to.userid = i.issue_to
```

In theory, you can join single table multiple times (there is no limit).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select username
from user
join issue on user.userid in (issue_to, issue_from)
where id = ?
```